# Bootstrap 5 dismissable alert isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have an alert in my `html` code:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="alert" style="display:none;">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
    <span id="msg">Success</span>
</div>
```

Initially, the alert should be hidden. Upon clicking the submit button in my script, it should show the `danger` alert. This is my `js`:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",function(){
     document.getElementById("alert").className="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center";
     document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Danger";
     document.getElementById("alert").style.display="block";
})
```

But when I execute the code, the alert isn't hidden at all. Secondly, upon clicking the submit button, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting
> 'className')

Why is that? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Does the style flag !important helps for hiding?

style="display:none !important;"

this is how i got it to work fine:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="alert" style="display:none !important;">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
        <span id="msg">Success</span>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="click me">

    <script>
        document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.getElementById("alert").className = "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center";
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Danger";
            document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "block";
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Now, the alert doesn't even show after clicking `submit`

Comment: When I try to `console.log(document.getElementById("alert").style.display)`, nothing shows

Comment: You can see a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/kxgdj0uq/